# ios modify registers to call function

Tags: ios, debugging, assembly, gdb, lldb

i connect to iphone's debugserver and able to send [GDB Serial Protocol](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Packets.html) packets. I can set breakpoint and wait until it reached. When it did i want to call objc_msgSend with known parameters, get it's output and continue execution. For now i am simulating it's process in xcode and lldb, so i can not use just 'call objc_msgSend(object, _cmd)'.

what i do:

- set breakpoint to some code
- register read pc // read next operation address
- register write lr 0x0x0000253a // set return address to continue execution (pc value)
- register write pc 0x30300c88 // my objc_msgSend address
- register write r0 0x16ed30 // my object address
- register write r1 0x3161 // my selector address
- breakpoint set -a 0x0x0000253a
- continue

So i have my method called, but then app crashes and never reaches my 'return address' 0x0x0000253a. Also it rewrites r0 with return value, so my method is totally incomplete. I understand that what i do is hardcore overwriting registers without storing and restoring previous values so please help. How can i store/restore registers state, what i am doing wrong or what necessary things i do not do?

Also it could be very helpful to trace xcode's debugger for what it is doing while 'call objc_msgSend'. I tried to use [this code](https://github.com/crackleware/idevice-app-runner) and fruitstrap to use dtruss and then research it's output - it had thousands of memory reads and breakpoint sets, useless for me.

Note: i can use only GDB Serial Protocol.